# Replace can not find container with id

Tags: java, android, replace

I use drawer menu and fragments in my project. And when I run my project, i see the error in the log. How can I fix this error?

the code fragment in MainActivity

```
if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.gandash, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

the code of activity_main.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/gandash"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

the error while i start running
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSx02.png)

```
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:checkDebugClasspath UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
C:\Users\User\Desktop\vp-site\app\src\main\java\com\example\user\client_vp\MainActivity.java:144: error: cannot find symbol
            ft.replace(R.id.gandash, fragment);
                           ^
  symbol:   variable gandash
  location: class id
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
17 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 12 up-to-date
```

Comment: try clean build and invalidate/restart

Comment: Please add the full Stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: I tried several times, even rebooted my computer, I even had to reset the settings of Android Studio

Comment: Did you check if you're correctly use the layout with `setContentView()`?

Comment: Yeah, can you show us your full activity code?

Comment: Post your activity code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's noting but sync issue. 
Please try to restart your android studio from File > Invalidate Cache/Restart ..

After Restarting don't forget to clean your project

- Build -> Clean Project
- Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files